# Impersonate Azure Service Principal from a Google Service Account

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, google-iam

I'd like to obtain temporary credentials for an Azure Service Principal (SP) using a Google Service Account JWT token. This is needed for calling Azure APIs from a GKE workload, without having to store long-term SP credentials in GKE.

Is such federation possible for GCP -> Azure (I know it is for Azure -> GCP, based on [1], as well as GCP -> AWS [2]), and how to achieve it?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp_oidc.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why can't you store the credential in GKE, assuming that your workload is secure.

You will probably need a broker service that the service can authenticate to and fetch a temporary credential. In that case, you will not need to store the credential in GKE for long term.

However, the threat model is still the same, if your workload is compromised, the attacker can also impersonate your workload and fetch credential using the broker service.

Comment: Thanks - this option is always on the table, though I don’t agree the threat model is the same (otherwise, why would we need short-term credentials at all?). I’m looking for impersonation specifically in this case.

Comment: Having short term access token does hv advantage. Maybe a token is leaked and the attacker will not be able to have long-term access to your service. But if the attacker is able to compromise the application completely, having short-term or long term creds will have the same consequence. So, yup I guess you are correct. In that case, having a broker service should help. The service will issue new token and reboke the old one periodically.