# Sign in to Azure B2C with a Google Service Account

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to start with a Google Service Account credential (either opaque access token or ID JWT) and end with an Azure B2C credential. Is something like this possible with Azure? I'm not seeing any APIs for doing it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect

Note: this is conceptually similar (but different in terms of target identity) from another question I asked earlier:
[Impersonate Azure Service Principal from a Google Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856215/impersonate-azure-service-principal-from-a-google-service-account)

EDIT: Our use case for this is exchanging Google Service Account credentials that represent an *untrusted* client (e.g. a user in the system), for a user token in Azure B2C. Unfortunately, this eliminates the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate), as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Could you explain what is your end goal/ use case ? I will help a lot understanding what you're trying to achieve

Comment: It’s rather simple - if we have an app deployed on Azure that uses B2C, then in addition to authenticating regular web users, we’d also like to authenticate machine users programmatically. This is trivial on other identity platforms like GCIP, but not here.

Comment: Or put in other words, we want to exchange provider OIDC JWT token (Google, Azure, or any other) for an Azure B2C token. How the provider token is generated shouldn’t matter (as long as it’s signed with verifiable provider’s PK).

Comment: if the service principal (service account) is an Azure AD app you could use the client credential gant flow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications

Comment: Yep, but this is for "untrusted" clients ;-) So we should treat every Service Account as just another user, not a typical app->app auth.

Comment: In other words, our starting point is Service Account keys and not OAuth client creds.

Comment: what do you mean by service account key ? oauth client cred = client_id + clint_secret or cert which is the same

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys and it is not the same :-)

Comment: Yes it is the same, the "keys" are certificates and it is using oauth flow

Comment: it is using private key + pubkey, which is not the same as client_secret + client_id :-)

Comment: and in any case, the client-credentials flow that you mention is only valid for "trusted" server-server communication, it is not appropriate for untrusted clients like we're dealing with here. If it was this easy I wouldn't ask ;)

Comment: And if you think this could work, then I kindly ask you to please create a full answer with detailed instructions on how you think this could work. I'd be glad to be shown wrong here!

Comment: @Thomas I took a deeper look into what you suggested and while it could indeed enable us to exchange Google Service Account credentials for an Azure B2C access token (thanks for pointing it out!), my point unfortunately still stands that this is only appropriate for "trusted" server -> server communications.

The reason I asked (apologies if this wasn't clear) is that in our use case, we have a "pet" SA for each user, and each SA represents a user in the system (and users have access to their keys). So we can't use this flow, I think.

Comment: No worries, what are users do with this SA ? Should they be able to use themselves the key to get a token or are you building something to make think easier for them ?

Comment: Both - for some use cases (e.g. CLI access) they use the key themselves to generate a token, and for others (web workflows) the token is generated for them. I think we've used them historically as a substitute for long-living user refresh tokens, which are harder to rotate and are more coarse in terms of access control. Theoretically, we could transition to a system without user-accessible keys, but practically this would be complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD B2C only supports interactive federation flows with other identity providers.

Google service accounts are non interactive authentications. The only way AAD B2C can pass these credentials to Google would be through its REST API interface.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile

The credentials would need to be hard coded into the policy or through AAD B2C “policy keys”.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

From what I can see, AAD B2C REST API interface doesn’t support an authentication method that Google needs. So I would conclude it’s not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the API, we haven’t seen it before I think. I’ll dive a little deeper to confirm your second point.

Comment: OK to clarify, so this API can only be used to customize user flows (e.g. to implement additional auth factors), but it can only be triggered after a user initiated their sign-in/sign-up flow using regular means already? In that case, this is not what we're looking for, indeed.

Comment: Yes that’s correct, I conclude what you want is not possible.

Comment: Alright, marking as "resolved" for now unless there are other ideas :)